# Display Two Kdeplots on Same Jointplot Python Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization, seaborn

I have the following code for a jointplot:

```
joint_shot_chart = sns.jointplot(shot_df.LOC_X, shot_df.LOC_Y, stat_func=None,
                                 kind='kde', space=100, color=cmap(0.1),
                                 cmap=cmap, n_levels=50)
```

But I want to divide the data up and instead have two overlayed kdeplots, something like:

```
made_shot_chart = sns.kdeplot(shot__made_df.LOC_X, shot__made_df.LOC_Y, color=cmap(0.1), cmap=cmap, n_levels=50)

missed_shot_chart = sns.kdeplot(shot__missed_df.LOC_X, shot__missed_df.LOC_Y, color=cmap(0.1), cmap=cmap, n_levels=50)
```

But, I would like to overlay these over a background sketch, and have them appear on the same plot. How would I do this? The best case scenario for me would be to add them both into one jointplot somehow, is that possible? I'm new-ish to seaborn so I'm not sure the logical way to get this done.

Comment: For displaying 2 kde-plots on the same figure, you could re-design the (pandas) dataframe in such a way that, there is a new column that indicates if the data belongs to 'made' or 'missing' set and then use that column as the 'hue' parameter of the jointplot function.

Comment: As of overlaying this on a background sketch, could you explain what kind of sketch you have at hand? @lowlyprogrammer